# Sql server - default

Tags: sql, sql-server, default

Boa noite, criei uma tabela para testar o default do sql server:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

fiz um select para ver se os valores padrões do default foram inseridos mas vocês podem ver na imagem que isso não ocorreu. Quando é que ele insere esses valores padrões? Eu achei que esses valores eram inseridos quando fosse passado valores nulos ou vazios. Outro problema é que a data inserida foi de 1900 e isso só acontece nesse caso, porque se eu passar o getDate() no insert a data a salvar será a atual.

Comment: Vi que o valor padrão é inserido se você não passar no insert os campos que contenham o default, no caso o nome e a data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você insere **''** no banco de dados , ele **NÃO** entende isso como `valor não informado` e sim como `string vazia` . Sendo assim no campo varchar ele armazena a string vazia e no campo date converte pra 1900-01-01.

Como você não informou a ordem dos campos e quais campos vão ser inseridos no seu **insert** ele segue a ordem da sua tabela. Exemplo:

Se você fizer `insert into [testes5] (nome) values ('josé')` o campo data vai receber o `getdate()`.

Se você fizer `insert into [testes5] (data) values ('2015-01-01')` o campo nome vai receber o `padrão`.

ou se quiser fazer o insert sem informar a ordem e campos inseridos como tentou pode fazer

```
insert into [testes5] values (default,default)
```

Comment: Exato, percebi isso. Postei uma resposta praticamente ao mesmo tempo que você rs. Eu achava que passar vazio ou nulo fazia com que o valor padrão fosse inserido. Valeu!

Comment: Legal ! Completando um pouquinho a resposta , uma situação que o default pode ser bem útil é quando você adiciona uma nova coluna na sua tabela que não permite null e a tabela ja está populada.

Comment: Entendi. Teria como alterar uma coluna null para not null usando o default?

Comment: Acho que não , eu faria o seguinte , update tabela set coluna = default where coluna is null . Pra depois alterar a coluna pra nao aceitar nulll

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [testes5] (
  `id` integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Padrão',
  `data` date DEFAULT getdate()
)

INSERT INTO [testes5] (nome, data) VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT)

SELECT * FROM [testes5]
```

Se você especificar um valor sem string ou NULL, será reconhecido como valor em branco ou nulo ao invés de não especificado, fazendo com que não seja inserido o valor padrão.

Comment: Acho que você não compreendeu a minha pergunta. A minha dúvida era se passado valores nulos ou vazios registrava-se o valor padrão ou então em quais casos esses valores seriam inseridos. Vi que o valor padrão é inserido se você não passar no insert os campos que contem o default. De qualquer forma, valeu.

Comment: Exato! ...Desculpa pelo mal entendido, esqueci de explicar na minha resposta.
Se você especifica a coluna e valor no INSERT (independente se não tiver string ou for NULL) o SQL vai reconhecer aquilo como um valor em branco, ou seja: Você especificou um valor para aquela coluna, por tanto não será inserido o valor padrão. Resposta atualizada!

Comment: Sem problema, valeu!